# MyEclipse and making an EAR file

Tags: file, ear

I made an enterprise application in MyEclipse, and it made three projects.
The application name is Foo, and MyEclipse made these three projects:
Foo, FooWeb, and FooEJB.
I am able to deploy Foo in MyEclipse's server (which I set up as Glassfish), and when I expand the application in the server view in MyEclipse, I see the web and EJB modules.

Now I'd like to deploy to another Glassfish server, so I'd like MyEclipse to make an EAR file.
Then when I have the EAR file, I'm assuming that there is a place to copy it to in the Glassfish directory.

At this point, any help in telling me if MyEclipse is able to make an EAR file from these three projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this. When you go to deploy the application, instead of choosing the glassfish server that you use for development you will need to add a deployment. Choose the option that allows you to save it to the file system, instead of using the glassfish server that you use for development. Then make sure it is a "Packaged" deployment and not an "exploded" deployment. If I still had access to MyEclipse I would show you screenshots, but I'm not able to since it was at my last job.

Comment: I only see that I am able to deploy an application in a server, meaning, I need to pick a server, then deploy to it. You seem to be saying that I start with the application, then pick the server? If so, I do not see how this is done. I only see that I make a server, then pick the application, not the other way around.

Comment: I found an Export function, it made the EAR.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great. I'm glad you were able to figure it out. I was referring to a new "server" where the deployment folder is on your hard drive. Then you go to that location and pick up the ear file that is ready to deploy.